# Unity Input System: Rebinding composite parts

Tags: unity, c#, input

I have controls for movement defined as composite Binding through Vector 2D.

[image: Definition]

I have shown in settings any single binding which is not composite. I understood that I must get a composite index for binding, which is correct, I got the right binding like up, down, ...

But whenever I click on button for change something on Move, whole game freezes. And I can't do anything... Is there something I'm missing, when rebending part of composite?

Here is my code and screen, how the control settings looks.

```
public void Start()
{
    Button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
    {
        Key.Text = "Listening";
        
        _operation = Action.PerformInteractiveRebinding()
            .WithTargetBinding(BindingIndex)
            .Start();
        
        _operation.OnApplyBinding((op, path) =>
        {
            Action.ApplyBindingOverride(BindingIndex, path);
            Key.Text = Action.bindings[BindingIndex].ToDisplayString();
            _operation.Dispose();
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Binding]

Comment: Please don't post code in form of images, there is a code markup for it and it makes it way harder for people to recreate your issue.

Comment: Right, code repaired.

Comment: Nope. I know how to rebind it, I use the WithTargetBinding, but when I try to rebind it, the game freezes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the package manager, and select the Input System package. You can open the samples dropdown and select the Rebinding UI example. This contains an example for rebinding composite aswell. I would suggest looking at that as it contains a lot more information compared to my answer here.

When I tested your code and compared it to the example, I think your problem originates in the following line:

```
_operation = Action.PerformInteractiveRebinding()
    .WithTargetBinding(BindingIndex)
    .Start();
```

I think it should be like this for it to work properly:

```
_operation = Action.PerformInteractiveRebinding(BindingIndex)
    .Start();
```

Don't ask me why as I actually haven't used the new input system yet. But in the test I did this made a difference...

Comment: God... It really works. I wouldn't think of it...